# How to use MassTransit

Tags: c#, servicebus, masstransit

I want to test MassTransit as a ServiceBus for a project I'm doing. I started a new console application and got MassTransit from Nuget.

I found the documentation on the project site (http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html), and copied the code to my console project, but it seems that the code in the documentation is not updated.

for starters, the following are not part of the configurator any more:

```
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient()
```

When I comment them out and try to run it throws an exception:

```
   at MassTransit.ServiceBusFactory.New(Action`1 configure) in d:\BuildAgent- 02\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Configuration\ServiceBusFactory.cs:line 46
   at MassTransit.Bus.Initialize(Action`1 configure) in d:\BuildAgent-02\work\aa063b4295dfc097\src\MassTransit\Bus.cs:line 59
   at MassTransitTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\ophir_o\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MassTransitTest\MassTransitTest\Program.cs:line 14
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Is there any updated documentation for using MassTransit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem - in case anyone else is starting out with it and encounters it. There is a need to download another Nuget/Binary for the transport protocol being used by your app and reference it (in my case MSMQ).